# Admob ads not showing in different devices

Tags: android, admob

I compiled my code android in 3 devices (Samsung S5,Samsung Note 8 and Nexus 5) , the banner ads not showing in Samsung S5 , and the Interstitiel ads not showing in Samsung S5  and Nexus 5 . But it's works both (Interstitiel ads and banner ads) in note 8 .  Please tell me Why ? Thanks.

**This is the build.plugin(module : app):**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mypackage"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    compile "commons-io:commons-io:+"
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
```

Images of different devices I use:

[image: Images of different devices I use]